# How to change header margins through Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Google Docs released new options for controlling header margins Nov, 2018.
https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/10/vertical-ruler-table-header-size-google-docs.html

How I can change these options through Google Apps Script? Is it possible? I can't find any information about header margins on the official documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/header-section and on any other posts related to GAS.

I will be glad of any information on this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not all Google Docs features have a Google Apps Script method to create/insert/modify them but it is also true that some methods were spotted before they were officially announced like the partial text formatting for Google Sheets cell values, I think because [autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#using_autocomplete).

> **Using autocomplete**
>
> The script editor provides a "content assist" feature, more commonly called "autocomplete," which reveals the global objects as well as methods and enums that are valid in the script's current context. To show autocomplete suggestions, select the menu item Edit > Content assist or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. Autocomplete suggestions also appear automatically whenever you type a period after a global object, enum, or method call that returns an Apps Script class. For example:
>
> - If you click on a blank line in the script editor and activate autocomplete, you will see a list of the global objects.
> - If you type the full name of a global object or select one from autocomplete, then type . (a period), you will see all methods and enums for that class.
> - If you type a few characters and activate autocomplete, you will see all valid suggestions that begin with those characters.

Regarding how to make a feature request please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features

Comment: Thanks. I know about this feature and checked autocomplete methods again, but still not see any methods related to header margins. If Google Apps Script not have this feature, What should be my next steps? Is it possible to request this functionality from google or should I look for workarounds?

Comment: @IvanPereverzev See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features

Comment: Great! I created feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123737764

Answer (score -1):

`DocBody.setMarginTop()` should do the job, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: `body.setMarginTop()` only sets the margin of the `body` and NOT of Header!